# How to code a Download/Upload Speed Monitor in PHP,Python, or Java?

Tags: java, php, python, networking

I have to code a up/download speed monitor. It will obtain the current download and upload transfer speed of the computer which it has been installed and post it to another server periodically.
c
But I don't have an idea about how to catch instant transfer rates of a computer. As you know some of network monitoring programs can trace it but I could not find anything written in PHP, Python or Java?

Comment: PHP? Do you envisage this as a web application then? It doesn't appear to be one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JPCAP](http://netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii/jpcap/doc/index.html) (a java packet capture library-sniffer) is suitable for this job and I've done it.

Answer (score 3):

You don't say which operating system you're interested in.

A quick google turned up this: http://excess.org/speedometer/

"Measure and display the rate of data across a network connection or data being stored in a file"

Opensource, written in Python

Comment: Paul, thanks for that. This application will run in Windows and Linux. I will install it to all PCs in the house and my digital TV receiver box.